# How do you implement mod_wsgi on web servers?

Tags: python, apache-2.2, mod-wsgi, wsgi

All of the documentation I've seen outlines the process for self-managed Apache configuration. I currently have my site hosted through Media Temple. Is it possible to configure WSGI for these types of hosting providers? The only form of Python support I see from MediaTemple is CGI.

Comment: Which type of service do you have?

Comment: What do you mean by service Ignacio?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can support WSGI through a [FastCGI](http://www.fastcgi.com/drupal/) adapter such as [Flup](http://trac.saddi.com/flup) if your provider supports FastCGI.

(Although MediaTemple seems to only support VPS-type environments, so I'm not sure why you can't run whatever you want...)